# How to open gwt designer in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I installed plugin for eclipse - gwt eclipse plugin 3.0.0 when I right-click on the corresponding class or on ui.xml there I do not see designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Release Notes for 2.7.0](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_7_0_RC1):

> GWT Designer doesn’t work with 2.7 and is no longer supported.

Comment: Thank you. Are there programs similar to it?

Comment: There are editors for Sencha - [Sencha Architect](https://www.sencha.com/products/architect/#overview) and for Vaadin - [Vaadin Designer](https://vaadin.com/designer). Sorry, I don't know any _pure_ GWT editors...